# How to check the field is empty or not based on alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am writing a query for getting a customer list from database. The query contains a where condition to check customer's email is empty or not.

```
The original query:

SELECT ID
FROM MAINTABLE m 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER c
ON m.CUS = c.CUS
WHERE c.EMAIL <> ''
```

Howevery, in my case. **delivery_type** is a SSRS parameters and used to represent the email field is empty or not
. If the value is 'A' means the email field is empty, 'B' is not. I have tried below query but it seems totally wrong.
Anyone can help me on this issue?

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN c.EMAIL = '' then 'A' WHEN c.EMAIL <> '' THEN 'B' END 'delivery_type'
FROM MAINTABLE m 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER c
ON m.CUS = c.CUS
WHERE delivery_type = @delivery_type
```

Comment: `IS NULL / IS NOT NULL` ? Not clear what you mean "passed from SSRS parameters" I don't see parameters here

Comment: sorry it should be : WHERE delivery_type = @delivery_type

Comment: Still not getting it, what has the parameter got to do with A and B where used against the email? Please explain *clearly* what you are trying to do

Comment: Once the client select the delivery_type  A, I want to return the customer list don't have email and vice versa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE delivery_type = @delivery_type AND (
    (@delivery_type = 'A' AND email = '')
    OR
    (@delivery_type = 'B' AND email <> '')
)
```

Comment: May I know more about this statement, or any keywords that can help me searching it

Comment: Just standard logic and/or logic. Think about what you want to happen, formulate that in your head in English, then write the code for it